# When does a POVM correspond to projective measurements (without ancillas)?

Tags: quantum-measurements

Consider a POVM given by the following set of elements $\{E_i = M^\dagger_i M_i\}$ such that $\sum_i E_i = I$ [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM#Post-measurement_state) says that the condition $M_i^2 = M_i$ implies that the measurement is a projective one.

Consider the POVM given by $\{\frac{1}{2}\vert 0\rangle\langle 0\vert, \frac{1}{2}\vert 1\rangle\langle 1\vert, \frac{1}{2}\vert +\rangle\langle +\vert, \frac{1}{2}\vert -\rangle\langle -\vert\}$.

It would seem that the condition $M_i^2 = M_i$ is not enough to call it a projective measurement or is this considered a projective measurement even though the eigenspaces are not orthogonal?

Comment: That POVM is not a projective measurement. What makes you think it could class as one? (I mean, other than the fact that it *doesn't* satisfy the only criterion you mention.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, on Wikipedia (last lines of the section linked in the question), it says that that if the POVM elements satisfy $M_i^2 = M_i$ the POVM reduces to a projective measurement. I assume this statement is incorrect - Is the correct statement that $M_i M_j = \delta_{ij}M_i$?

Comment: That's a different question, and the example you provide directly detracts from that question. It may well be a theorem that $M_i^2=M_i$ $\forall i$ and $\sum_i M_i^\dagger M_i = I$ imply $M_iM_j=0$ for $i\neq j$, or it might not be true, but that decision is untouched by your example, which doesn't satisfy $M_i^2=M_i$ for any of its members.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Ah oops, I think I see my error now. Just to clarify $M_1 = 1/\sqrt{2}\vert 0\rangle\langle 0\vert$ and similarly for the other $i$, correct? I forgot about the $1/\sqrt{2}$ but this is what makes $M_i^2\neq M_i$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. For more on that, see [Kraus operators of a POVM](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/457169/kraus-operators-of-a-povm).

Comment: Thank you - I'll delete this question since it came out of a simple error on my part!

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I could close it or accept your answer if you move it from the comments to an answer if that's more appropriate! Btw, I think your last comment went on the wrong question :)

Comment: Well, one cannot comment on deleted posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you seem to be thinking that the operators in 
$$\left\{\frac{1}{2}\vert 0\rangle\langle 0\vert, \frac{1}{2}\vert 1\rangle\langle 1\vert, \frac{1}{2}\vert +\rangle\langle +\vert, \frac{1}{2}\vert -\rangle\langle -\vert\right\}$$
satisfy the criterion $M_i^2=M_i$. This isn't the case, because of the below-unity factors on each operator: taking $E_1=\frac{1}{2}\vert 0\rangle\langle 0\vert$ as an example, an [appropriate (hermitian) square root](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/457169/kraus-operators-of-a-povm) giving $E_1=M_1^\dagger M_1=M_1^2$ is
$$
M_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\vert 0\rangle\langle 0\vert,
$$
where you need to take the squre root of the factor in front. This then means that $M_1^2=E_1$ differs from $M_1$ by a factor of $1/\sqrt 2$.